# Issue moving shapes in picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I got a problem when trying to move shapes in a picturebox, the shape move correctly when selected, but is trapped in a small zone, I can't move it in the whole picturebox. I was wondering if my issue is in the paint event or the move event, because I have no problem while drawing shapes in the whole picturebox.

Here is the code :

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
                pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

                MyPoint tempPtDep = new MyPoint(e.X, e.Y);
                ((Shape)listBox1.SelectedItem).gsPtAcc = new MyPoint(
                      Math.Min(ptdep.x, tempPtDep.x),
                      Math.Min(ptdep.y, tempPtDep.y));

                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (shapeList != null)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            foreach (Shape elem in shapeList)
            {
                if(elem.Equals(listBox1.SelectedItem as Shape))
                {

                    pen = new Pen(Color.RoyalBlue, 3);
                    pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
                }
                else
                    pen = new Pen(elem.Couleur, 3);


                if (elem is Segment)
                {
                    seg = elem as Segment;
                    seg.WDraw(g, pen, seg.gsPtAcc);
                }
                else if (elem is Circle)
                {
                    cercle = elem as Circle;
                    cercle.WDraw(g, pen, cercle.gsPtAcc);
                }
                else if (elem is Square)
                {
                    carre = elem as Square;
                    carre.WDraw(g, pen, carre.gsPtAcc);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your `Min`s with `ptdep` are the culprit. Where is `ptdep` coming from in your code?

Comment: From mouse_down, it's taking the mouse position from the event arg

Comment: So, you are talking the `Min` in both directions (x, y) of the current mouse position and the position where you clicked the mouse. What is this trying to do? I would guess you can move that way only up and left. That seems to be the issue here. Are you trying to implement Drag&Drop?

Comment: No not really, so what should I do to go right and down too (math isn't my strong point :s)

Comment: Looks like to me the whole `Min` part is unnecessary, if you just want to move the `Shape` to where the mouse is currently. The event get's only fired while you are over the `PictureBox` so try just `((Shape)listBox1.SelectedItem).gsPtAcc = new MyPoint(tempPtDep.x, tempPtDep.y);`. There are other things that you need to take care off, like you don't check if anything is selected at all, or what is selected is indeed a shape. Since I don't know why you are capturing the `Mouse_Down` point, what you are exactly trying to do, and obviously code is missing, this is the best advise I can give you.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem thanks a lot Frank. Don' worry I check if something is selected and all, I just didn't put it in my post because if I did, I would have to put more code, so I kept it simple. I thought about `((Shape)listBox1.SelectedItem).gsPtAcc = new MyPoint(tempPtDep.x, tempPtDep.y);` but that didn't work, the shape didn't move properly. What I did at the end is giving the new point to `ptdep` and so using it instead of tempPtDept, that became pointless anyway :) Thanks again

Comment: Glad it works now. What you describe makes perfect sense if you want to use the mouse down as an "anchor point" and want to move relatively to that. That's why I asked if you are doing Drag&Drop. The difference is you don't want to hold the mouse button down but other than that it behaves the same way. I wish you would have mentioned that, I could have helped you earlier.